# How is this raster image animation accomplished? Magic?

Tags: image, web, animation, raster

I have been wondered about this for several years now. And it comes up increasingly regularly for me (I do mostly product and design some web dev) and now I have some thoughts on how it could be used very powerfully for some new projects but I need to understand it technically. There are some cases where I see still raster images that have had animation added to them on the web, yet they are not video so they can be used with much more versatility and as I understand it with lower performance impact. Riot games uses it frequently, here's is and example on one of their sites. (scroll down to the Agents section with the red background): https://playvalorant.com/en-us/?gclid=CjwKCAiA8OmdBhAgEiwAShr403pomRb6Wqu1mwgbgfR8AbeuJs1FROTT6E_rSZw5QjXu8zNnS61hvRoCvq4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds .
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZGgO.png)
I need to understand how the art here was authored and implemented. Can anyone help me learn this?

I inspected it and there seem to be several components that make it up but I can't make any sense of it all. Are people doing this onto something too sophisticated to be common use? I have looked at some animation tools and searched everywhere for info and I'm not finding any clues.

Comment: It's a canvas that is being animated by code. See the function startAnimationFrame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is this HTML animation of raster images accomplished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102039/how-is-this-html-animation-of-raster-images-accomplished)